# Border around Images when making PDF in PDFBox

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I have been using PDFBox to generate pdf files and was wondering if it is possible to add a border around images. If not, is there some algorithm that allows you to efficiently draw lines precisely around the image? I have the following code that allows myself to add an image to a pdf page:

```
//image for page 2
public File processPDF()
{
    //creating pdf
    PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
    File file = new File("NWProofReference.pdf");

    //adding first page to pdf, blank
    PDPage page = new PDPage();
    PDPageContentStream contentStream;

    try {
            BufferedImage awtImage = ImageIO.read(new File(PDFProcessing.image));
            PDXObjectImage ximage = new PDPixelMap(document, awtImage);
            float scale = 1.0f; // alter this value to set the image size
            contentStream.drawXObject(ximage,100,400, 
            (ximage.getWidth()*scale,ximage.getHeight()*scale);
            contentStream.close();

            document.save(file);
            document.close();
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    return file;
}
```

Using this or any code, is there any way to actually add a border around the image itself that is made available through the PDFBox API?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's some code that adds a red border:

```
        BufferedImage awtImage = ImageIO.read(new File(PDFProcessing.image));
        PDXObjectImage ximage = new PDPixelMap(document, awtImage);
        float scale = 1.0f; // alter this value to set the image size
        contentStream.drawXObject(ximage,100,400,ximage.getWidth()*scale,ximage.getHeight()*scale);
        // these three lines are new
        contentStream.setStrokingColor(Color.red);
        contentStream.addRect(100-3, 400-3, ximage.getWidth()*scale+6, ximage.getHeight()*scale+6);
        contentStream.closeAndStroke();

        contentStream.close();
```

good luck! You can of course change the "3" to a smaller number.

Comment: Wow, less code and even has sharper corners than mine does. Awesome answer. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks... as a bonus, you can also have a look at setLineCapStyle and setLineJoinStyle to see different styles in edges / line ends.

Comment: I will definitely look into it.

Comment: There have a parenthesis missing at this line
`contentStream.drawXObject(ximage,100,400,(ximage.getWidth()*scale,ximage.getHeight()*scale);`

Comment: IMHO it's rather one too much, I have removed it. Thanks! (hopefully I got it right)

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find anything parto f the API that allows border creation, but I did come up with some code that would allow us to create a slim and clean border around images using:

```
 PDPageContentStream.drawLine(xStart, yStart, xEnd, yEnd)
```

Adding onto the code I posted in my question, here is my answer:

```
public File processPDF()
{
    //creating pdf
    PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
    File file = new File("NWProofReference.pdf");

    //adding first page to pdf, blank
    PDPage page = new PDPage();
    PDPageContentStream contentStream;
    float titleWidth, titleHeight, width, height;

    try {
        BufferedImage awtImage = ImageIO.read(new File(PDFProcessing.image));
        PDXObjectImage ximage = new PDPixelMap(document, awtImage);
        float scale = 1.0f; // alter this value to set the image size
        xStart = 100; //left most x position of image
        yStart = 400; //bottom most y position of image
        width = ximage.getWidth()*scale; //width of image
        height = ximage.getHeight()*scale; //height of image
        contentStream.drawXObject(ximage,xStart,yStart,width, height); //draw image

        //start to draw border
        contentStream.drawLine(xStart, yStart, xStart + width, yStart); //bottom 
        contentStream.drawLine(xStart, yStart + height , xStart + width, yStart + height); //top
        contentStream.drawLine(xStart, yStart, xStart, yStart + height); //left
        contentStream.drawLine(xStart + width, yStart, xStart + width, yStart + height); //right

        document.save(file);
        document.close();
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    contentStream.close();
    return file;
}
```

Hope this helps and future users of PDFBox for java!